# form reset error in angular 1.5 with controller As syntax

Tags: angularjs, forms

using angular 1.5 and this is very basic problem

When I click reset button of form ; it gives error in console

***Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined***

below is my relevant code

#### form.html

```
 <form name="loginForm" ng-controller="LoginController as vm" ng-submit="vm.login(credentials)" novalidate >  
  ...form details ...
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warn" ng-click="vm.reset()">Reset</button>
```

#### login.controller.js

```
login
  .controller('LoginController', function($scope){
    var self = this;

   self.reset = function () {
      self.loginForm.$setPristine();
      self.loginForm.$setUntouched();
    };
```

even I tried with  `form="form.loginForm"` but no success

Kindly suggest what is the issue. here is [my full code plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/0lRlyu1g7UOS7xX2eALF?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access your `form` in your controller and you are using the `controller as` syntax, just change your form name to this format: `name="alias.formName"`

Since you are using `vm` when you declared your controller as `ng-controller="LoginController as vm"`, your form should be:

`<form name="vm.loginForm" ng-controller="LoginController as vm" ng-submit="vm.login(credentials)" novalidate >`

Also don't forgot to change your `ngMessages` block as well.

```
<div ng-messages="vm.loginForm.username.$error" ng-if="vm.loginForm.username.$touched">
   <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
   <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
</div>
```

**Updated:**

Using `$setPristine` only makes the form `$pristine`, and it does not reset the value of your form fields. If your goal is to also reset the form field values, then you have to set `self.credentails = {username: '',password: ''}` in your reset function.

Comment: that doesn't help either

Comment: @pro.mean It's working when I edited your plunk. Did the error still occur? Or when you said that 'that doesn't help either ', is it because the values in the form fields are not reset?

Comment: and how to do that? i write  `self.credentails = angular.copy(self.loginForm.credentials);` in reset() but it does not clear

Comment: Thanks. I repeatedly failed to remember for the same form.

Comment: Set  `self.credentails = {username: '',password: ''}`. `self.loginForm` does not contain the `credentials` object.

Comment: even it work in my local  but does not work in plunker. will you check this for a while

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116043/discussion-between-alex-andrea-and-pro-mean).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

1. You're not using the same version of angular and angular-messages
2. Your plunkr doesn't use `ng-controller="LoginController as vm"`, but `ng-controller="LoginController"`
3. You're expecting the form to be in the controller, but it's in the $scope, since you used `name="loginForm"` instead of `name="vm.loginForm"`

Comment: that is typo. I'll fix it

Comment: it is necessary to use same version of ng-message? there is no latest version than 1.4.9 and plunket also failed to add

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. All the official angular modules are released at the same time, with the same version, and are tested to work together. You can't be sure that ngMessages 1.4.2 will work fine with angular 1.5.6 and ngRoute 1.0.3. And yes, there is a newer version: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-messages.js